# vue filter by checkbox true or false value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, data-binding

In my vue app I am wanting filter a list to show only entries that have been moderated.

What I am finding though is the when the checkbox is checked, I get all the results that are true, and when the checkbox is unchecked I get all the results are false, however what I am wanting is that when the checkbox is empty no filtering takes place, and when the checkbox is checked I get results that have been moderated.

here is my attempt,

`<input type="checkbox" v-model="showUnModerated" /> Show only unmoderated listings</label>`

My filter code,

`return this.listing.listings.filter(listing => (this.showUnModerated ? 1 : 0) === listing.moderated);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an array of modified list and `v-model` with your checkbox.Thus you can get the modified list.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showChecked: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <input type="checkbox" value='1' v-model="showChecked" /> element 1</label> <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value='2' v-model="showChecked" /> element 2</label>
  <br> {{showChecked}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the condition of filter to return all entries when the checkbox is empty(this.showUnModerated is false).

return this.listing.listings.filter(listing => (this.showUnModerated ? (1===listing.moderated) : true);

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.